# Как реализовать цикл?

Tags: phpexcel, php

Есть цикл

```
// Картинки
        $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
        $imagePath = $this->image;
        $r=2;
        foreach($data as $value){
            $objDrawing->setPath($imagePath);
            $objDrawing->setCoordinates("D".$r);       
            $objDrawing->setHeight(200);
            $objDrawing->setWidth(200);
            $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
            $r++;
        }
```

При попытке выводить изображения выдает ошибку

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
> 'PHPExcel_Exception' with message 'A
> PHPExcel_Worksheet has already been
> assigned. Drawings can only exist on
> one PHPExcel_Worksheet.

Если убираю цикл, то выводит одно изображение. Как вывести все изображения?

Comment: @zupers, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

`new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();` в цикл поместите